# Is there a C# token counter?

Tags: c#, static-analysis

I want to have a programming competition with a friend of mine in C# and the competition will be to write with the fewest number of C# tokens. I have seen C++ token counting programs around but is there one for C#? Or would there be something in System.Reflection? Additionally, if anyone has links to token counters for other languages, feel free to link them.

Comment: @RaYell - ?? Surely the counter is needed to work out who has won...

Comment: Correct, the person who has the fewest tokens wins, but nothing stops each having access to the counter as they write to give an idea of progress.

Comment: In the spirit of competition, why don't you start one with your friend to write the smallest token counting program?  You should only have to do lexical analysis, that isn't hard.

Answer (score 3):

[Irony (a C# parser)](http://irony.codeplex.com) has a C# grammar (i'm not sure which version of C# it supports), and the grammar explorer tool that Irony comes with probably gives you a token count...

If it doesn't, im sure you could make it do so pretty easily (open source ftw)

Answer (score 0):

Well I believe that technically anything in the Reflection namespaces won't be a token counter, as everything in Reflection deals with inspection of the IL, which may be optimised for example.

This wikipedia entry might help you however - [List of C Sharp lexer generators](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_C_Sharp_lexer_generators)